# AnimationDrawable.isRunning() always return true

Tags: android, android-animation

I faced a strange behavior.
If I start `AnimationDrawable` with `start()`, then after animation is finished, method `isRunning()` will still return true. It is "one-shot" animation, which is not looped.

Here is an example code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private AnimationDrawable cartoon;
    private ImageView iv;
    private BitmapDrawable frame0, frame1;
    private final int sleep=1000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        cartoon = new AnimationDrawable();
        cartoon.setOneShot(true);
        frame0 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.gridx0));
        frame1 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.gridx1));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(iv==null) iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        cartoon.addFrame(frame0, sleep);
        cartoon.addFrame(frame1, sleep);
        iv.setImageDrawable(cartoon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(cartoon.isRunning()) Log.d("AnimationTest", "Animation already started");
        else cartoon.start();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is output:

```
02-22 14:18:42.187: DEBUG/AnimationTest(2043): Animation already started
02-22 14:18:52.093: DEBUG/AnimationTest(2043): Animation already started
02-22 14:18:52.166: DEBUG/AnimationTest(2043): Animation already started
...and so on.
```

So animation runs for the first time and then `isRunning` will return true forever.
[I also found similar issue posted to code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6945#c1), but it was closed w/o any comments

My questions is:

1. Is there a real bug or did I misunderstood something?
2. How can I tell when `AnimationDrawable` is finished?

Comment: Does it start the animation over again when you click it in addition to logging, or is it *just* logging?

Comment: Goebits: no, animation does not starts again when I click it second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.java#AnimationDrawable), I can only come to the conclusion that setting it to oneshot means it truly *is* a oneshot animation, with no repeat. At least, not without calling `stop()` first.

If you call `stop()` once it's done, then the next call to `start()` works fine(in my test, at least). How you call `stop()` is up to you, but you could schedule a timer to run it after the total duration has elapsed when you call `start()`. Not having callbacks in this class does kinda suck.

If you'll be using this mechanism often, it might be worth extending `AnimationDrawable` to give it callbacks. If you do, you should post it up somewhere to make it easier on yourself and others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try extending `AnimationDrawable`, declare your own boolean field that will be used as flag. Override `isRunning()` and return the boolean field instead. Change the flag based on your class animation listener (start, repeat, end). :)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no animation listener available for AnimationDrawable

Answer (score 0):

On way to handle animation's end is to calculate the total animation's duration and to send an event after that duration is expired.

```
    private AnimationDrawable timerAnimation;

...

private void startTimerAnimation() {
    int timerAnimationDuration = calcTimerAnimationDuration();
    timerAnimation.start();
    timerAnimationEndHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, timerAnimationDuration);
}


private int calcTimerAnimationDuration() {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < timerAnimation.getNumberOfFrames(); i++) {
        total += timerAnimation.getDuration(i);
    }
    return total;
}


private Handler timerAnimationEndHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        onTimerAnimatonFinished();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

What happens if You try:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(cartoon.isRunning()){
      Log.d("AnimationTest", "Animation already started");
      return false;
   }else{
       cartoon.start();
      return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: The same: 02-22 15:00:19.617: DEBUG/AnimationTest(2285): Starting animation for the first time
02-22 15:00:19.638: DEBUG/AnimationTest(2285): Animation already started
02-22 15:00:23.524: DEBUG/AnimationTest(2285): Animation already started
02-22 15:00:23.537: DEBUG/AnimationTest(2285): Animation already started

Comment: This is so, because return value here just means touch event was handled